# Making a simple grid of lists

Tags: python, list

Hello guys I need help with doing gaming grid of game Man don't get angry.
I should do a function which makes a grid of format `n*n` [this is how it look for n=9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGHz7.png)
and I need to do it generally for every odd number, the width of arms is 3 and the length is `n`. It should be done with list of lists because then I have to make a figure to go around this grid so I will need the coordinates. 
I made this gaming grid by for cycle

```
def gensachovnicu(n):
    matica='*'' '
    matica1='X '
    matica2='D '
    for j in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            if i<((n-3)//2) and j<((n-3)//2):
                print('  ',end='')
            elif i<((n-3)//2) and j>(n-((n-3)//2)-1):
                print('  ',end='')
            elif i>(n-((n-3)//2)-1) and j<((n-3)//2):
                print('  ',end='')
            elif i>(n-((n-3)//2)-1) and j>(n-((n-3)//2)-1):
                print('  ',end='')
            elif i==(n//2) and j>0 and j<(n-1) and j!=(n//2):
                print(matica2,end='')
            elif i==(n//2) and j==(n//2):
                print(matica1,end='')
            elif j==(n//2) and i>0 and i<(n-1):
                print(matica2,end="")
            else:
                print(matica,end='')
        print()
```

but it is so long and I cant handle him.

Comment: This is a story, not a question.

Comment: dont get angry.

Comment: note: `uneven = odd`

Comment: "but it is so long and I cant handle him." What does this mean?

Comment: Start by dividing responsibilities. Write one def that takes an List of Lists and prints them, create a datastruct that is your playing field (def to create it), remeber the coords of your playstone and on changing its posiition clear the datacell in the list of ists and put it to the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for responsibility-dividing:

```
from random import randint

def dice():
    return randint(1,6)

# true for all fields (including border ones and player) 
def IsField(n, x,y): 
    off = (n-3)//2 # offset to the sides of 3 spaces playing ground

    if (x >= off and x < n-off):
       return True
    if (y >= off and y < n-off):
        return True

    return False


# true only for border 
def IsBorder(n,x,y): 
    off = (n-3)//2
    mid = (n-1)//2 # the middle where player moves

    if (y >= n) or (x >=n) or (y<0) or (x<0):
        return False
    if (y == 0 or y == n-1) and x in [mid-1, mid, mid+1]:
        return True
    if (x == 0 or x == n-1) and y in [mid-1, mid, mid+1]:
        return True
    if (y > 0 or y < n-1) and x == mid:
        return False
    if (x > 0 or x < n-1) and y == mid:
        return False
    if ((x == off or x == off+2) and not x == mid):
       return True
    if ((y == off or y == off+2) and not y == mid):
        return True

    return False


# what to mark field with?
def GetMarker(n,x,y):
    if IsBorder(n,x,y):
        return '*' 
    else:
        return ' '


# repair wrong inputs to odd and minimal 9
def MakeOddMin9(n):
    if n % 2==0:
        n += 1 # make odd
    n = max(9,n) # min 9
    return n


# construct the board, player pos still missing
def MakeBoard(n):
    n = MakeOddMin9(n)
    base = [ [GetMarker(n,x,y) for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
    mid = (n-1)//2
    base[0][mid] = 'a' # add player      
    return (base,(mid,0))


# print the boards fields
def PrintBoard(board):
    print("")
    size = len (board) 
    for y in range(size):
        row = ""
        for x in range(size):
            row += board[y][x]

        print (row) 
    print ("")

def Move(b,x,y,nx,ny):
    b[y][x]='*'
    b[ny][nx]='a'


# moves player along 1 tile  
def MoveOne(board,player):
    actX = player[0]
    actY = player[1]
    mid = (len(board)-1)//2
    # right
    if IsBorder(len(board), actX+1, actY) and actY < mid:
        Move(board,actX,actY,actX+1,actY)
        player = (actX+1,actY)
    # down
    elif IsBorder(len(board), actX, actY+1) and actX > mid:
        Move(board,actX,actY,actX,actY+1)
        player = (actX,actY+1)
    #left
    elif IsBorder(len(board), actX-1, actY) and actY > mid:
        Move(board,actX,actY,actX-1,actY)
        player = (actX-1,actY)
    #up
    elif IsBorder(len(board), actX, actY-1) and actX < mid:
        Move(board,actX,actY,actX,actY-1)
        player = (actX,actY-1)

    return (board,player)


b, player = MakeBoard(19)
mid = (len(b)-1)//2

PrintBoard(b)
inputKey= ''
while(inputKey == ''):
    moves = dice()
    b[mid][mid] = str(moves)
    for n in range(0,moves):
        b,player = MoveOne(b,player)

    PrintBoard(b)        
    inputKey = input("\n Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.").lower()
    if (inputKey != ''):
        break
```

Output:

```
   *a*
   * *
   * *
**** ****
*       *
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


   ***
   * *
   * *
**** a***
*   4   *
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   ***
   * *
   * *
**** ***a
*   3   *
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   ***
   * *
   * *
**** ****
*   1   a
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   ***
   * *
   * *
**** ****
*   5   *
**** ****
   * a
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   ***
   * *
   * *
**** ****
*   4   *
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   a**


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   ***
   * *
   * *
**** ****
*   4   *
**a* ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   ***
   * *
   * *
*a** ****
*   5   *
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.

   *a*
   * *
   * *
**** ****
*   6   *
**** ****
   * *
   * *
   ***


 Hit enter. Enter anything to quit.
```

Comment: The player should moves around the middle so moving on stars.

Comment: You can check if a field is a border tile with `IsBorder(board,x,y)` - or by checking `if board[y][x] == '*'` in a correctly initialized board. If you replace your gamepiece's position with a `'*'` after checking if `IsBorder(board,newX,newY)` and set `bord[newY][newX]` to whatever is your gamepieces representationchar you can move it along the edge.  IF you need help with the game mechanics, spec the rules in a new post and link it to this one - maybe someone will help. This question was about making a grid of lists of lists ....

Comment: @Item  now it moves.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time
import random
doska = []

n=int(input('Zadaj rozmer hracieho pola:'))
def create_sachovnica(n):
    global doska
    doska = [[' ' for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    npol = n // 2
    for i in range(n):
        doska[npol - 1][i] ='*'
        doska[npol + 1][i] ='*'
        doska[i][npol - 1] ='*'
        doska[i][npol + 1] ='*'
    doska[npol][0] ='*'
    doska[npol][n - 1] ='*'                                                 
    doska[0][npol] ='*'
    doska[n - 1][npol] ='*'
    for i in range(1, npol):
        doska[npol][i] ='D'
        doska[npol][n - i - 1] ='D'
        doska[i][npol] ='D'
        doska[n - i - 1][npol] ='D'
    doska[npol][npol] ='X'


def print_sachovnica(n):
    for n in doska:                                                               
        print(' '.join(n))
    print()

def gensachovnicu(n):
    create_sachovnica(n)                                
    print_sachovnica(n)



def nextpos(doska, x, y):
size = len(doska)
if x >= size // 2:
    if y < size // 2 and doska[x - 1][y] == '*':
        return x - 1, y
else:
    if y <= size // 2 and doska[x][y + 1] == '*':
        return x, y + 1
    elif y <= size // 2 and doska[x-1][y] == '*':
        return x-1,y
if y >= size // 2:
    if x <= size // 2 and doska[x + 1][y] == '*':               
        return x + 1, y
    elif x < size // 2 and doska[x][y+1] == '*':
        return x,y+1
    elif x > size // 2 and doska[x][y-1] == '*':
        return x,y-1
    elif x > size // 2 and doska[x+1][y] == '*':
        return x+1,y
else:
    if x > size // 2 and doska[x][y - 1] == '*':
        return x, y - 1
    elif x > size // 2 and doska[x][y - 1] == '*':
        return x, y - 1
return x, y

def nextpos2(doska, s, r):
velkost = len(doska)
if s >= velkost // 2:
    if r < velkost // 2 and doska[s - 1][r] == '*':
        return s - 1, r
else:
    if r <= velkost // 2 and doska[s][r + 1] == '*':
        return s, r + 1
    elif r <= velkost // 2 and doska[s-1][r] == '*':
        return s-1,r
if r >= velkost // 2:
    if s <= velkost // 2 and doska[s + 1][r] == '*':  
        return s + 1, r
    elif s < velkost // 2 and doska[s][r+1] == '*':
        return s,r+1
    elif s > velkost // 2 and doska[s][r-1] == '*':
        return s,r-1
    elif s > velkost // 2 and doska[s+1][r] == '*':
        return s+1,r
else:
    if s > velkost // 2 and doska[s][r - 1] == '*':
        return s, r - 1
    elif s > velkost // 2 and doska[s][r - 1] == '*':
        return s, r - 1
return s, r



def pohyb(n, x, y, s ,r):
while True:
    create_sachovnica(n)
    doska[x][y] = 'A'
    doska[s][r] = 'B'
    hod=random.randint(1,6)
    hod1=random.randint(1,6)
    if hod ==1 :
        x, y = nextpos(doska, x, y)
    elif hod==2:
        for i in range(hod):
            x, y = nextpos(doska, x, y)
    elif hod ==3:
        for i in range(hod):
            x, y = nextpos(doska, x, y)               
    elif hod==4:
        for i in range(hod):
            x, y = nextpos(doska, x, y)
    elif hod == 5:
        for i in range(hod):
            x, y = nextpos(doska, x, y)
    elif hod ==6:
        rozhodnutie1 = str(input('Pohyb(P)/Nova figurka(N)'))
        if rozhodnutie1 == 'P':
            for i in range(hod):
                x, y = nextpos(doska, x, y)
        else:
            doska[n-1][((n - 3) // 2)] = 'A'
    if hod1==1:
        s, r = nextpos2(doska, s, r)
    elif hod1==2:
        for i in range(hod1):
            s, r = nextpos2(doska, s, r)
    elif hod1==3:
        for i in range(hod1):
            s, r = nextpos2(doska, s, r)
    elif hod1==4:
        for i in range(hod1):
            s, r = nextpos2(doska, s, r)
    elif hod1==5:
        for i in range(hod1):
            s, r = nextpos2(doska, s, r)
    elif hod1==6:
        rozhodnutie=str(input('Pohyb(P)/Nova figurka(N)'))
        if rozhodnutie=='P':
            for i in range(hod1):
                s, r = nextpos2(doska, s, r)
        else:
            doska[0][((n-3)//2)+2] = 'B'
    print_sachovnica(n)
    print(hod)
    print(hod1)
    time.sleep(1)

gensachovnicu(n)
pohyb(n,(n-1),((n-3)//2),0,((n-3)//2)+2)
print(figurky(n))
```

Comment: I make it like this , but i have a question. How can i allow an entrance for the figure ? and how can i fix figure in "house" ?